# Wordpress is adding <!-- page-who-we-are.php --> to the top of page

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Wordpress is adding this comment above all HTML on my site which is causing problems in IE in which the site won't render properly at all.

How do I stop WP adding this?

Comment: have you checked header.php? also, WP debugging 101 - disable all plugins, change to 2012 theme, enable plugins one by one until you find whichever one is adding this (if the problem is from a plugin). Also this question may be better suited for wp answers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Pretty sure that is a specific theme issue... I know changing to 2012 theme isn't always an easy solution.. just search all your files for that text and then 'safely' remove whatever is doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to search for files by content and search inside wp-content folder of your WordPress for this string: "page-who-we-are.php" - you'll locate the string and you can remove it.

To search files by content on Windows, see [Best way to confidently search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service](https://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an)?